# No connection is active/available to service this operation: HMGET /api/v1/students; UnableToConnect on tutor-helper.redis.cache.windows.net:6380

Tags: asp.net, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to connect to an Azure Cache For Redis. I'm using .net 6 and I use StackExchangeRedis to cache a response, it works in localhost but in deployment is not working, please help me ....
I also find an answer in many Forum but ain't work

[Error when deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnk6g.png)

My code config for Redis

application.json

```
"RedisCacheSetting": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "ConnectionString": "tutor-helper.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=*****PuCERKKnrcbff0y3hWpZ***m1BaY40=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"
  },
```

Cache Attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class CachedAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        private readonly int _timeToLiveSeconds;

        public CachedAttribute(int timeToLiveSeconds)
        {
            _timeToLiveSeconds = timeToLiveSeconds;
        }

        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            var cacheSetting = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<RedisCacheSetting>();

            if (!cacheSetting.Enabled)
            {
                await next();
                return;
            }
            var cacheService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IResponseCacheService>();
            var cacheKey = GenerateKeyFromRequest(context.HttpContext.Request);

            var cacheResponse = await cacheService.GetCacheResponseAsync(cacheKey);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheResponse))
            {
                var rs = new ContentResult
                {
                    Content = cacheResponse,
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    StatusCode = 200,
                };

                context.Result = rs;

                return;
            }

            var executedContext = await next();

            if (executedContext.Result is ObjectResult okObjectResult)
            {
                await cacheService.CacheResponseAsync(cacheKey, okObjectResult.Value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeToLiveSeconds));
            }
        }

        private static string GenerateKeyFromRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            var keyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            keyBuilder.Append($"{request.Path}");

            foreach (var (key, value) in request.Query.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
            {
                keyBuilder.Append($"|{key}-{value}");
            }

            return keyBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Config in startup.cs

```
 public static void SetUpCache(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var redisCache = new RedisCacheSetting();
            configuration.GetSection(nameof(RedisCacheSetting)).Bind(redisCache);
            services.AddSingleton(redisCache);

            //services.Configure<RedisCacheSetting>(configuration.GetSection("RedisCacheSetting"));

            //services.AddDistributedRedisCache(op => op.Configuration = redisCache.ConnectionString);
            services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(op => op.Configuration = redisCache.ConnectionString);
            services.AddSingleton<IResponseCacheService, ResponseCacheService>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output of a simple tcping to the endpoint:

> tcping tutor-helper.redis.cache.windows.net 6380
> Probing 52.163.188.36:6380/tcp - No response - time=2021.946ms
> Probing 52.163.188.36:6380/tcp - No response - time=2013.493ms
> Probing 52.163.188.36:6380/tcp - No response - time=2014.854ms
> Probing 52.163.188.36:6380/tcp - No response - time=2006.678ms

So, the DNS name resolves to a real IP address, but the endpoint isn't accepting connections.

If I were to guess, I would say that you have a firewall rule setup on the redis instance that is blocking the connection?

Comment: I'm found that I block my IP on the azure portal and I delete it and its work :))